# *.docx file in an "out stream" - can't be opened by MS Word

Tags: python, web2py, docx

Inside of `web2py` framework I want to return MS Word *.docx file as *a download stream*. I do it as shown in the code below. But when the file download process is done **one can't open it in MS Word**.

Code:

```
from io import BytesIO 
filename = 'empty_file.docx'
filepath = os.path.join(request.folder, 'uploads',filename )
# read a file from file system (disk)
with open(filepath, 'rb') as f: 
    out_stream = BytesIO(f.read())
response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=%s" % filename
response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'
return out_stream.getvalue()
```

**What might be the problem?**

When I *manually download* the same file I could *easily open it in MS word*! 
[image]

### Update 1

Checking checksum (md5) issued in files being not equal.

```
openssl dgst -md5 empty_file.docx
MD5(empty_file.docx)= b5be5d79e57f73303c9df9c420b64a43
```

[image]

### Update 2

**Size comparison**

11462 bytes `empty_file.docx` - original at a web hosting.

11311 bytes `empty_file.docx (4)` - downloaded to my PC.

**Zip footer**

```
$ unzip -t empty_file.docx
Archive:  empty_file.docx
testing: [Content_Types].xml      OK
testing: _rels/.rels              OK
testing: word/_rels/document.xml.rels   OK
testing: word/document.xml        OK
testing: word/theme/theme1.xml    OK
testing: word/settings.xml        OK
testing: word/fontTable.xml       OK
testing: word/webSettings.xml     OK
testing: docProps/app.xml         OK
testing: docProps/core.xml        OK
testing: word/styles.xml          OK
No errors detected in compressed data of empty_file.docx.
```

But still I've no clue how to fix it...

Comment: Have you actually compared the checksum of the downloaded file with the original, and looked at exactly where/how they differ? Do the sizes match? If not, how different are they? Does it still have a valid zip footer? You're providing some code, but not enough context to know if that code is actually the place where the problem is.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy , how can I do count checksum of a downloaded file /of original file with python?

Comment: `md5sum`, if you have it. `openssl dgst -md5` will do the job, if you have that but not a standalone `md5sum` command. For Windows, see [this post on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/245775/is-there-a-built-in-checksum-utility-on-windows-7).

Comment: ...whereas for the sizes you can just use `ls -l`/`dir`, and `unzip -t` (on UNIX) to check whether the file still has a valid ZIP footer.

Comment: What does manually download mean? How do you "manually download"?

Comment: @Sraw, go to the `upload` folder [of web2py framework] of pythonanywhere.com file system and download - http://joxi.ru/n2Yzp84cow0V5A